# rm deleting files very slowly

Tags: bash, rm

I've written the below script in Bash to delete files given a specific numeric range:

```
# *** Declare variables ***
SRC="${1}"
START="${2}"
END="${3}"

# *** Delete frame range ***
for frame in $(seq -f "%08g" "${START}" "${END}")
    do
        rm -vf "${SRC}${frame}"*
    done
```

It works fine on my tests, but when I run it from a live server, it deletes files at snail pace. Is there any reason why rm runs so slow?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of file system does the server use?

Comment: is this your server or a VM e.g. on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

in each of the:

```
rm -vf "${SRC}${frame}"*
```

The shell needs first to expand that glob to construct the list of arguments to pass to `rm`. To do that it needs to read the contents of the directory and match each file name against the pattern.

For instance, if `$SRC` is `foo/bar`, and `$frame` is 00000000, it needs to read the full contents of the `foo` directory and match all the entries against the `bar00000000*` pattern, and if there are a lot of files, that can take a long time.

`rm`, in turn will need to locate those files in the directory which may take time if the directory is huge and not indexed. Then removing the file implies modifying the directory (and update its index if any) which again may be costly for huge directories.

At least you should try to expand only one glob, to avoid that shell having to read the entire directory for each frame.

With `zsh` which has a `<first-last>` decimal integer number range glob operator:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
src=$1 start=$2 end=$3

[[ $# -eq 3 && $start = <-> && $end = <-> && $end -ge $start ]] || {
  print -ru2 "Usage: $ZSH_SCRIPT:t <src> <start> <end>"
  exit 1
}
set -o extendedglob

range="(<$start-$end>~^?(#c8))" # range expressed on 8 characters
rm -vf -- $src$~range*
```

If you run into the system's limit on how many arguments can be passed to a command, you can change the last line to:

```
print -rN -- $src$~range* | xargs -r0 rm -vf --
```